# Leaflet external link without popup

Tags: leaflet

I am trying to create a link beetween an external menu (img) / a marker / a div (content) - not using bindpopup.

I managed to create a link to open the bindpopup.

This is my marker :

`var markers = [];
var marker1 = L.marker([43.55,7.02],{title:"marker_1", icon: ballicon}).addTo(map).bindPopup('Villes de CANNES');
markers.push(marker1);`

This my link :

`<div class="item">
            <a id="marker_1" href="#">
            <table class="cannes" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="150" styleborder="0" width="250"><tbody><tr><td valign="top" background="cannes-250x150.jpg" height="150"><div id="numcannes">1</div>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td class="titlecannes" height="25">Cannes</td></tr></tbody></table></a>
            </div>`

But instead of open the bindpopup I would like to zoom on the marker and open the popup content in a div.

I can do it by clicking on the marker :

`var marker1 = L.marker([45,1],{title:"marker_1", icon: ballicon, clickable: true,
name: 'Cannes Place', type: 'City'}).on('click', onClick).addTo(map);function onClick(e) {  $('#content').html("<p><strong>Name:</strong> "+this.options.name+"</p><p><strong>Type:</strong> "+this.options.type+"</p>")};`

... but I do not know how to open the content in div by clicking on my img.

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your content to be utilizing in Leaflet's Popup functionality, why involve Popup at all? Simple attach the properties you need to the options hash of Leaflet's Marker, and go from there. Then I would assume you could bind to your image(although I would use an actual IMG tag instead of the deprecated `background` attribute on a TD) with

```
$("#marker_1").click(function(){
    map.setView(marker_1.getLatLng(),10);
    //set content of #content here
})
```